# PHP MySQL Requery vs Refresh

Tags: php, mysql, real-time

I have a webpage that run a query on a db and reports the results. Currently the page auto refreshes itself every 10 seconds in order to display (almost) real-time data.

This is probably a very inefficient way of accomplishing this but as of right now I'm not really sure what alternatives there are.

What options do I have to present real-time data on a php webpage?

Comment: depends you can use websocket

Answer (score 0):

you can use node.js and socket.io. This is great example to get you started:

http://book.mixu.net/ch13.html

or you can use [ejabberd](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CCwQFjAA&url=http://www.ejabberd.im/&ei=1i0HUtCkEtGSswaR54DIBQ&usg=AFQjCNGnoQmxGR4RSVeQ_bHxFk2ytGOfNg&sig2=Ho1mYMfrMK19CZobJQxWBg&bvm=bv.50500085,d.Yms) and [strophe](http://strophe.im/) js library.

I used both of that solution for real time stuff and I found node.js and socket.io much easier to implement.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what your data is for and how you are using it, ive recently started putting data display functions into seperate pages and then using jquery to load those pages into dives on my main page at page load and then reloading the divs on a timer and on a reload function if the refresh is needed sooner, that way your whole page does not refresh making it flash and go blank but instead the data just gets nicely updated.

```
   var paused = false,
auto_refresh = setInterval(
function()
{
if (paused) return false;
$('#mot').fadeOut('slow').load('motview.php?view1=$dayd&viewdate=1').fadeIn('slow');
$('#work').fadeOut('slow').load('workview.php?view1=$dayd&viewdate=1').fadeIn('slow');
$('#motday').fadeOut('slow').load('motdaylist.php?    view1=$dayd&viewdate=1').fadeIn('slow');
$('#notelist').fadeOut('slow').load('notelist.php?dayd=$dayd').fadeIn('slow');
}, 60000);
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#mot').load('motview.php?view1=$dayd&viewdate=1');
$('#work').load('workview.php?view1=$dayd&viewdate=1');
$('#motday').load('motdaylist.php?view1=$dayd&viewdate=1');
$('#notelist').load('notelist.php?dayd=$dayd');

}); 
function reloaddivs()
{
$('#mot').load('motview.php?view1=$dayd&viewdate=1');
$('#work').load('workview.php?view1=$dayd&viewdate=1');
$('#motday').load('motdaylist.php?view1=$dayd&viewdate=1');
$('#notelist').load('notelist.php?dayd=$dayd');
};
```

the above im using to display 4 lots of data on one page that all updates nicely on a timer or after ive interacted with a page by calling reloaddivs

Answer (score 0):

Inspect your page carefully to identify exactly what is the data which is to be updated every 10 seconds - chances are it will not  be the whole page (menus, navigation, headers, footers).

Cache all that data say, every 10 minutes, or every hour - especially if data driving any of those elements are being dragged from databases.

Then include the panel containing the dynamic data.

Better yet might be to load the dynamic data using Ajax to refresh every n seconds.